# Using outlook.office.com OVERRIDES Windows 10 setting disabling Touchpad (!!!)

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchpad, device-manager

This is bizarre. When I use e-mail at office.outlook.com with the current and recent versions of Firefox the Touchpad gets intermittently ENABLED, completely destroying my productivity. Things happen that I don't want to.

I can't use a Touchpad.  I gave up. This laptop and all others. I use an external trackball mouse.

How in the world is that website overriding a Windows 10 setting??? This happens fairly often, and I haven't experienced this in any other scenarios.  When I go somewhere else (a different tab in Firefox, a different application) the Touchpad doesn't work (correct).  If I go to the Windows 10 setting right after my palm moves the mouse in outlook.office.com I find the Touchpad is supposed to be disabled.

To the point, how do I actually disable the Touchpad? Permanently.

I have attached a screencap showing the device I have already disabled in the Device Manager, and a list of other potential devices.

Firefox 95.0.2
Windows 10 21H1; Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eG0xxx

[image: Touchpad Settings]
[image: Device Manager]

Comment: That's wild. I don't understand how it could even function when disabled in Device Manager. Did you try disabling `HID-compliant mouse` as well or is that an externally attached mouse? I also see `Synaptics TPFHID Device ` and `Microsoft Input Configuration Device ` that you can try.

Comment: Wild.  And disturbing. What other Windows settings can Microsoft interfere with while on their websites??? When I disable HID-compliant mouse my external trackball-mouse stops working.  --- You seem to have hit the write devices.  When I disable those two I can no longer get to Touchpad Settings. The link shows in the search, but the link takes me to the top-level settings page, and only my trackball-mouse settings seem to be available now.  --- Hopefully this solves the problem.  (I can't imagine how it wouldn't.)  Thanks.

Comment: You might also try disabling Tablet Input Service... though it has side effects.

Comment: Can you confirm if you needed to disable both devices or just the `Synaptics TPFHID Device`?